# Highcharts large treemap How do I get the clicked node data?

Tags: highcharts

How do I get only the node data I clicked on? I fill **data** when get it from server.

When i get log **this** i can not find my need data.

I using Highcharts 8.0.0

```
{
        series: [{
            type: "treemap",
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            allowDrillToNode: true,
            layoutStartingDirection: "horizontal",
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHTML: true,
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'isw',
                    fontSize: '13px',
                },
                formatter: null
            },
            levelIsConstant: false,
            levels: [{
                level: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    style: {
                        fontFamily: 'isw',
                        fontSize: '13px',
                    },
                    formatter: null
                },
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
            data: null,
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    console.log(this);
                }
            }
        }]
    }
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-large-dataset/)

Comment: Are you asking about how to append children node to tree as you click on nodes instead of appending all children at once?

Comment: No. Suppose I have a list of provinces and cities. When I click on a province, I want to see the province and city data of that province. Using the click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount it!

```
events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    console.log(event.point);
                }
            }
```